# EntityFieldQuery INNER JOIN

Tags: 7, database

I'd like to run a query using the EntityFieldQuery object. I need value from both the node and node_access table therefore I'd need to use INNER JOIN. From the d.o documentation I can't figure out how this is possible.

Here's what I have --

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
->entityCondition('bundle', 'node_access')
->propertyCondition('type', 'external_link')
->propertyCondition('status', 1)
->fieldCondition('gid', '3', '=')
->fieldCondition('realm', 'domain_id', '=')
->fieldCondition('grant_view', '1', '>=')
->range(0,1)
->execute();
```

Comment: Although it can't be done on-the-fly in Drupal 7, it can be done in Drupal 8 (unreleased at the time of this writing). See [Entity Field query got join support](http://drupal.org/node/1882418) for details (including an example).

Comment: In Drupal 8 all conditions is Like that (->condition()). Ex of an EFQ in D8: $result = \Drupal::entityQuery('node') ->condition('type', array('entity_a', 'entity_b'), 'IN') ->condition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED) ->condition('field_myfield.value', '5', '=') ->execute(); In Drupal 8 EFQ the collumn is defined directly in name field by field_name.value or field_name.target_id in drupal 7 is `->fieldCondition('field_name', 'target_id', $entities_a, 'IN');`

Answer (score 30):

You can't add extra joins to an `EntityFieldQuery` directly (it's not supported), but you could add a tag to the query, implement [`hook_query_TAG_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_TAG_alter/7), and add the join manually when the query is converted down to a standard db query.

This isn't tested but will probably get you most of the way there:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'node_access')
  // etc
  ->addTag('MYTAG');

// get the query results as normal
```

And then the query alter function:

```
function MYDMOULE_query_MYTAG_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->join('node_access', 'node_access', 'node_access.nid = node.nid');
}
```

The other way to do it would be to subclass `EntityFieldQuery` itself and add the join, but I think the above method is simpler in this case.

Comment: Is there a better way to do it in a single function? Even if it's not `EntityFieldQuery`

Comment: Not really, the only other way is to build the query up manually using `db_select`, then you can have as much control as you want over it

Comment: I'll go with that. Thx

Comment: @Clive ... oh this answer is really interesting. Like it. :P

Comment: then you can vote it up :)

Comment: db_select though is slow. Beware that.

Comment: @Kevin It's faster than an `EntityFieldQuery` though...and a `db_query()` would be even quicker than that

Comment: can implement it on template file? how?

Comment: The `EntityFieldQuery`caches it's results, no? So I think the `EntityFieldQuery` is faster then `db_select` since the database is queried every time you use the latter, no?

Comment: @Michiel No `EntityFieldQuery` doesn't do any caching, it just wraps around a `SelectQuery` and adds some methods for entities. Those extra methods account for the slight (very slight) performance decrease you'd experience using it as opposed to a regular `SelectQuery`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using custom properties with your own tables, the tag method won't work.  You need to use subqueries instead:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user');

$roles_subquery = db_select('users_roles', 'ur');
$roles_subquery->fields('ur', array('uid'));
$roles_subquery->condition('rid', $my_role_id);

$query->propertyCondition('uid', $roles_subquery, 'IN');
```

See [Need a join in an EntityFieldQuery, how about a subquery?](https://www.frobiovox.com/posts/2015/06/10/need-a-join-in-an-entityfieldquery-how-about-a-subquery.html) for details.

Comment: Excellent solution for cases like mine, with custom tables. Awesome work!