# How to get node title using this query on template?

Tags: theming, modal-dialogs

Im building a custom filter in Drupal 8 based on some queries.

I got this already, here im filtering by values on body:

```
$query = db_select('node__body', 'n')
                            ->fields('n')
                            ->condition('n.body_value', "%" . $searchWord . "%", 'LIKE')
                            ->condition('n.bundle', 'mycontenttype');
     $getList = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Then i pass the variable to the Twig:

```
return [
            '#filters' => $getList,
```

In the twig im doing:

```
{% for oneItem in filters %}
```

But im unable to get the title of the node here, what im missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You shouldn't do queries like like that. You should use `EntityQuery`. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3Acondition/8.8.x and [EntityFieldQuery to search Content Type for text and select matching Nodes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45848/entityfieldquery-to-search-content-type-for-text-and-select-matching-nodes)
   `EntityQuery` will return the nids. Then use the node storage's `loadMultiple` to get the node themselves. Typically something like `Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids)`
2. I would expect the Node title would be gotten in your loop with `{{ oneItem.title }}`. 
   If that's not working I suggest installing and enabling the devel module, and sticking `{{ dump(filters) }}` in your custom template to investigate the structure you're getting

Comment: EntityQuery is available in Drupal 8?, im not using D7, sorry.

Comment: Now im using this but im just getting the nids and not the content: $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
              ->condition('type', 'contentType')
              ->condition('body', "%" . $getSearch . "%", 'LIKE');

Comment: EntityQuery is in Drupal 8, which you said you're using in the OP.

Comment: Im using Drupal 8 as you can see on my question, im only getting array of ids in my template and i need the node info, photos, title, body, this is what im getting: array(2) { [114]=> string(2) "50" [115]=> string(2) "51" }

Comment: Ok i got it working, thank you so much, the final result is: $nodes =  \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($getList);

        $getNodes = [];
        foreach ($nodes as $entity){
          $getNodes[] = ['id' => $entity->id(), 'label' => $entity->label()];
        }