# using EntityFieldQuery, how to order results based on a node reference field title and/or field collection item field, says name

Tags: database

I have a node which references another, I want to order the results based on the title of the referenced field title.

I'm using

```
function listAll(){
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
                    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'building')
                    ->fieldOrderBy('field_reference_area', 'title', 'ASC')
                    ->execute();

  $nodes = entity_load('node', array_keys($entities['node']));

  foreach($nodes as $key => $fac){
      dsm($fac);
  } 
}
```

Comment: so basically you need to use join to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this won't be possible using EntityFieldQuery. You could build your own query using `db_select()` and have full control over it.

You can refer to [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45785/entityfieldquery-inner-join) post and try to adapt it to fit your needs.

Comment: thxs !, it seems you are right

Answer (score 0):

You can use join using something like

`$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

  $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')

                    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'building')

                    ->fieldOrderBy('field_reference_area', 'title', 'ASC')

 ->addTag('JOINTABLE');

  ->execute();`

And now use this tag to join another table


`function MYDMOULE_query_JOINTABLE_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {

  $query->join('reference_table', 'r', 'r.nid = node.field_referencefield_value');

}`

This is just a sample example. Try to modified it with your need. :)