# entityQuery to get Nodes referenced by other nodes like an SQL JOIN

Tags: 8, database

I have an entity query to get content of type `article` that has a field that matches a given value, which works as expected.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->condition('type', 'article');
$query->condition('field_some_field', 'some value');
```

Now I have a second content type `detail_page` that has an entity reference to a node of type `article`. I would like to get content of type `article`, *same as before*, but only those that have been referenced in the `field_detail_page_article_ref` field of a `detail_page` content type.

Is that possible with Entity Queries? Playing around with the raw SQL, what I basically need to do is an `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` with the field `field_detail_page_article_ref` to see if the `nid` exists. But it doesn't seem like there is any sort of `join()` function available for entity queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EntityFieldQuery INNER JOIN](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45785/entityfieldquery-inner-join)

Comment: [Entity Field query got join support](https://www.drupal.org/node/1882418) in the meantime, you simply query for fields in the referenced entity and the join is added automatically, but this works only forward, not backwards like in this question.

Comment: @NoSssweat Is the solution you linked specific to Drupal 7? I'm using 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just had exactly the same problem with a Drupal 8 instance, and while I wasn't able to solve it with a single query as I'd've liked to, I did succeed with the following:

My goal was to get all the nodes of type A or B which meet certain criteria, one of which is that they are referenced by type C. (I've removed that other stuff here to focus on the issue.)
Type has an entity reference field which allows multiple entries to either type A or B.

First we get all the nids that are referenced:

```
$connection = \Drupal::database();
$query = $connection->query("SELECT DISTINCT field_name_target_id  FROM {node__field_name}");
$referenced_nids = $query->fetchCol();
```

Note that you'll need to adjust your code to match the name of your reference field. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/static-queries, which is where I ripped that bit from.

Then my query to get the actual nodes/nids:

```
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');

$query = $storage->getQuery();

$nids = $query->condition('type', ['TypeA', 'TypeB'], 'IN')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('nid', $referenced_nids, 'IN')
  ->sort('title')
  ->execute();
```

**UPDATE:** I learned today that the first step of my procedure is not considered proper by Drupal standards, as you shouldn't make direct queries on Drupal tables (see https://www.drupal.org/core/d8-bc-policy#schema). The following method is more brute force unfortunately, but caching the results should help.

Instead I refactored the first part using an EntityQuery.

```
// Get all the entities of type C, the referencing entity:
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'TypeC')
  ->condition('status', 1);
$typeC_nids = $query->execute();
$typeC_nodes = $storage->loadMultiple($typec_nids);

// Loop through the nodes and get all the references:
$referenced_nids = [];
foreach ($typeC_nodes as $node) {
 $references = array_column($node->field_name->getValue(), 'target_id');
 foreach ($references as $reference) {
   if (!in_array($reference, $referenced_nids)) {
     $referenced_nids[] = $reference;
   }
 }
```

}

Then use that list of the referenced NIDs in the second query.

Comment: Very clever! It seems so obvious to me now.

Answer (score 27):

You can use ['entity' field query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3Acondition/8.7.x)

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->condition('type', 'article');
$query->condition('field_some_field.entity:node.title', 'Referenced node title');
```

Comment: This is also a good answer since you can introspect field relationships using EntityQuery

Comment: Definitely the best and most elegant answer.

Comment: I would like to note that this doesn't answer the OP's question. This query would get articles referencing something in particular. The goal was to to get articles referenced by something in particular.

Comment: I cannot believe how deeply buried this crucial piece of information for querying entities. Thank you for this. This: "field_some_field.entity:node.title" kind of thing should be documented somewhere. Is it?

Answer (score 2):

An example using `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()`:

```
$entityTypeManager = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$nodeStorage = $entityTypeManager->getStorage('node');
$nodeStorage->loadByProperties([
  'type' => 'mycontenttype',
  'field_entity_reference_field.entity:node.nid' => 3786,
]);
```