# Get list of nodes by field-collection value

Tags: 7, entities

I am having `field_feature` as a collection of fields (`field-collection`) in a content type called 'watches'. Those fields are,

```
field_water_resistance -> water_resistance(Term Reference)
field_gender -> gender(Term Reference)
field_function -> function(Term Reference)
field_sub_function -> sub_function(Term Reference)
```

And so on.

I have my query like this:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('type', 'watches','=')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
$query->range($offset, 15);
$query->addTag('joinentity');
$query->addTag('fieldcollection');
$query->addMetaData('termscollection', $filterparams); // $filterparams is array of tids
```

Now I want to add above field collections in the query with the parameters (array of tids). How can we do that?

I know the EntityFieldQuery with the `entity_type` as `field_collection_item` but I don't know the same for `entity_type` as `node`.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to possibilities to solve this:

1. Looks like you already got a tag for joining the field_group entities here:

   $query->addTag('joinentity');

You could then implement `hook_query_joinentity_alter()` to implement the join, see also [EntityFieldQuery INNER JOIN](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45785/entityfieldquery-inner-join#45787)

2. You use db_select() or db_query() and add your joins there rather than an EFQ. I think this is preferable as implementing tags and hooks for those gets a bit messy IMO.